# How can you calculate the expected number of games until a certain profit?

Tags: probability

Let's define the following game:

1. You toss a coin until it falls on it's heads, call the number of tosses n.
2. If n is odd, you win $2^{n-1}$ dollars. If n is even, you win nothing.

The expected net win for this game is: $$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2k+1}}\cdot 2^{2k} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty 0.5 = +\infty$$

The chances of winning this game are:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2k+1}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2\cdot 4^k} = \frac{1/2}{1-1/4} = \frac23$$

**Question**:

If I set a target profit of p, how many games should I expect to play until my profit reaches p?

**Example**:

if p is 1$ then I would expect to play 1.5 times, since I only need a single win, which has 2/3 of chances of happening.

**Simulation**:

```
import random

random.seed(1)

def tossUntilHeads():
    n = 1
    while random.choice([True, False]):
        n += 1
    return n

def playUntilProfit(P):
    p = 0
    t = 0
    while p < P:
        n = tossUntilHeads()
        if n % 2 == 1:
            p += 2**(n-1)
        t += 1
    return t

P = 10000
t = playUntilProfit(P)
print(f'Games until {P}$ of profit: {t}, Avg Profit p/Game: {P/t:.2f}$')
```

Output: Games until $10000$\$ of profit: $3093$, Avg Profit p/Game: $3.23$\$.

Comment: This question has a certain Russian paradoxical feel to it. ;-)

Comment: On a more serious note, there may be a useful generation function attack on this problem. (Emphasis on *may*.) I'll look at it in a bit, unless someone answers it in the meantime. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's note $N(x)$ the number of games one would expect to have to play before having won at least $x$ dollars.

Let's try to express N(x) with N(y), y being smaller than x. Maybe we will find a nice induction. Obviously, $N(0)=0$.

When I need to win x, my game can have several issues:

- I may win nothing (P=1/3). In that case I still expect N(x) games to play.
- I may win x or more (P=2/3 if x=1, P=1/3 if x=2, P=1/6 if $x\in]2,4]$, more generally $P=2/3*(1/2)^{\lceil log_2(x) \rceil }$). In that case that game is my last one.
- I may win something ($4^w$), but $4^w<x$ ($P=2/3*(1-(1/2)^{\lceil \log_2(x) \rceil })$, but what matters is the individual probabilities). In that case I still expect $N(x-4^w)$ games to play.

To sum up, $N(x) = 1+(1/3*N(x) + 2/3*(1/2)^{\lceil log_2(x) \rceil }*0 + \sum_{w=0}^{\lceil \log_2(x)\rceil-1}(1/4)^{w+1}N(x-4^w))$

That simplifies a bit:

$$N(x) = 3/2*(1+\sum_{w=0}^{\lceil log_2(x)\rceil-1}(1/4)^{w+1}N(x-4^w))$$

But after that I don't see any nice way to simplify. Still, that gives a simpler way to calculate:

- $N(1) = (3/2)*(1+0) = 3/2$
- $N(2) = (3/2)*(1+(1/4)N(1)) = 33/16$
- $N(3) = (3/2)*(1+(1/4)N(2)) = 291/128$
- $N(4) = (3/2)*(1+(1/4)N(3))$
- $N(5) = (3/2)*(1+(1/4)N(4)+(1/4)^2N(1))$
- $N(1000) = (3/2)*(1+(1/4)N(999)+(1/4)^2N(996)+(1/4)^3N(984)+(1/4)^4N(936)+(1/4)^5N(744))$

This could also help you to check an hypothesis on the behaviour of $N(x)$. As you observed it seemed to evolve like $C\log_2(x+D)$ ($C$ and $D$ constant), we can plug that into our induction formula and see if that checks out.

$$C\log_2(x+D) \sim 3/2*(1+\sum_{w=0}^{\lceil log_2(x)\rceil-1}(1/4)^{w+1}C\log_2(x-4^w+D))$$

$$2/3\log_2(x+D) \sim 1/C+\sum_{w=0}^{\lceil log_2(x)\rceil-1}(1/4)^{w+1}\log_2(x-4^w+D)$$

$$\log_2((x+D)^{2/3}) \sim \log_2(2^{1/C})+\log_2(\prod_{w=0}^{\lceil log_2(x)\rceil-1}(x-4^w+D)^{(1/4)^{w+1}})$$

By doing X->2^X on each side:

$$(x+D)^{2/3} \sim 2^{1/C}\prod_{w=0}^{\lceil log_2(x)\rceil-1}(x-4^w+D)^{(1/4)^{w+1}}$$

For those two polynomials in x to be equivalent, we need their degree to be the same (also we need $2^{1/C}=1$, which is already impossible):

$$2/3 \sim \sum_{w=0}^{\lceil log_2(x)\rceil-1}(1/4)^{w+1}$$

Which is synonymous with:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{w=0}^{\lceil log_2(x)\rceil-1}(1/4)^{w+1} = 2/3$$

Which is equivalent to:

$$\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{w=1}^{u}(1/4)^{w} = 2/3$$

$\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{w=1}^{u}(1/4)^{w}$ is well-defined since $1/4<1/2$ and if it's equal to $L$ then $4L = 1+L$, so $L=1/3$. Sadly, our assumption that $N(x)\sim\log(x)$ is off. That said, it might be correct in the range of values that matter to you.

Comment: Is there any way to estimate this number without much work? I found that the experimental average profit $p$, after $n$ games, always sits close to $E[p] = 0.5 \cdot k$ where $k$ is the $(\log_{2} n+ 1)/2$.

Comment: @ozuromo If what you need is an estimation of this number for some value, then I recommend writing a script that calculates it. That's not too hard.